# Ambiguous solutions to the same exponential problem - help needed

Tags: inequality

I came across the below question in an IMO preparatory book and tried to solve it, I followed a certain steps and got a solution, but the book followed a slightly different approach and arrived at a totally different solution, I couldn't find any fault with both approaches.

The problems is as follows:

> Find the least value of $a$ for which $5^{1+x}+5^{1-x}$, $a/2$, $25^x+25^{-x}$ are three consecutive terms of an Arithmetic Progression.

**My approach :**

since the three terms are to be in AP

$a/2 = (5^{1+x}+5^{1-x}+25^x+25^{-x})/2$

$\Rightarrow a = 5\cdot5^x+5\cdot5^{-x}+5^{2x}+5^{-2x}$.  Let $5^x = t$ ***(Step A)***

Then $a = 5t+(5/t)+t^2+t^{-2}$. Now let $u=t+1/t$

$\Rightarrow a = 5u+u^2-2$, since $u^2 = t^2+t^{-2}+2$ ***(Step B)***

This is a quadratic $u^2+5u-(2+a) = 0$

for $u$ to be real $25+4(2+a) \ge 0$,

$\Rightarrow a \ge -33/4$.

I even tried maximizing the expression on the RHS in ***Step B*** , i.e. maximizing $u^2+5u-2$, then differentiating and equating to zero $2u+5 = 0$,

$\Rightarrow u = -5/2$, substituting this value in the expression

$(-5/2)^2+5(-5/2)-2 = -33/4$ **Same solution as above**

**Approach followed in the book below.**

It's the same up to ***step A*** mentioned above.

then the equation becomes

$a = (t-(1/t))^2 +5(\sqrt{t}-1/\sqrt{t}))^2 +12$

since there are two square expressions, the value of this expression is always $\ge12$, hence $a\ge12$.

Both approaches seem fine to me, can someone explain the ambiguity?

Comment: In your approach, $t$ can be any positive real number, thus $u$ has to be in $[2,\infty]$. So he condition is not that $\Delta \geq 0$, but: there is a solution that is $\geq 2$.

Comment: ok ,got it , Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

The expression $u=t+t^{-1}$ cannot take any value. First of all, $t=5^x>0$; the minimum of $u=t+1/t$ is taken at $t=1$ (AM-GM); hence $t+1/t\ge2$. All values $\ge2$ for $u$ can be obtained.

You then have
$$
a=u^2+5u-2\ge 4+10-2=12
$$

Comment: ok ,got it , Thanks very much.